# How can I set up a testbed LAMP stack on an Ubuntu 9.04 desktop installation?

Tags: ubuntu, lamp, perl, ubuntu-9.04

What's the best way to set up an Apache/MySQL/Perl CGI environment starting from an Ubuntu 9.04 desktop installation?  I'd like to be able to do this either from within a VM or on a "real" installation, if that makes any difference.

Which packages should I install, and are there any particular configuration guides that might be useful to me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

It installs everything for you.